# best practise for sspi user

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-server-2008-r2, sspi

I am currently setting a web and sql windows server for a 3 mvc web applications. I have got a sspi domain user set up but not familiar at the correct and most optimal setup for such.

Do all app pools get set up with this user?
Do all databases on the sql server get read/write permissions for this user?

I am looking for best practise for when working with an sspi user.

Comment: I think this is a good question and should not have been closed.